# VsCode: collapse other sidebar sections(views/viewlets) when one is expanded

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VsCode sidebar contains a lot of sections/views: Folder, Open Editors, Outline, NPM scripts and maybe others could be added by extensions. They are all stacked vertically and usually there is no room to display full content of them all. So one have to constantly click small arrow-like collapse buttons and drag section borders with mouse to view needed section content.

I would like to be able to focus on a needed section with keyboard shortcut and auto-collapse others. As I understand there is no such built-in setting so maybe I have to write extension for that. But I've never written VsCode extensions before and unfamiliar with API.

So my questions: is it possible to write such extension and which API's should I use to achieve my goal? Or maybe there is some other way? Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer but ... see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#moving-views-from-the-sidebar-to-the-panel which you might find helpful.  You will be able to move views like Outline to the panel (where Terminal, etc. are) so they don't stack up in the sidebar and are full size when clicked.  Over time I would expect that more views will be movable to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the focus to any View, both built in and contributed by extensions. You just have to look for the commands **#Activity Bar: Focus on #View**, like `Explorer: Focus on Timeline` or `Bookmarks: Focus on Explorer`.

But, these commands will not collapse the other views contained in the same Activity Bar.

About extension development, unfortunately, there is no API to control Activity Bar or Views, the way you want. You can only define the way a view will be displayed, but nothing to *update* theses atributes. So, if you really need this, you should open a feature request in VS Code repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).